# Python - Having trouble iterating through XML files, searching for text, and replacing it where needed

Tags: python, xml, loops, text, replace

I have several thousand .XML files. Some of the text needs to be changed, as the files were generated with the wrong label. I need to iterate through all of them in a given directory and make the changes where needed. Here is an example of a file in the directory:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>resized</folder>
    <filename>P123584521_009.jpg</filename>
    <path>D:\Users\path_to_image\P123584521_009.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1024</width>
        <height>1024</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>575</xmin>
            <ymin>548</ymin>
            <xmax>866</xmax>
            <ymax>759</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>827</xmin>
            <ymin>449</ymin>
            <xmax>1024</xmax>
            <ymax>798</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>198</xmin>
            <ymin>505</ymin>
            <xmax>559</xmax>
            <ymax>747</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>592</xmin>
            <ymin>730</ymin>
            <xmax>787</xmax>
            <ymax>945</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>362</xmin>
            <ymin>756</ymin>
            <xmax>597</xmax>
            <ymax>1008</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>219</xmin>
            <ymin>748</ymin>
            <xmax>376</xmax>
            <ymax>894</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Green plant</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>648</ymin>
            <xmax>351</xmax>
            <ymax>1024</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

There are 7 annotations, all entitled "Green plant." I need to replace each occurrence of that phrase with just "Plant." Here is the code I wrote to try to do this:

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys

path = 'D:\\Users\\directory_with_all_xml_files'

files = os.listdir(path)

for file in tqdm(files):
    filename, filetype = file.split('.')
    if filetype == 'xml':
        #Open file
        xml_file = open(file)
        new_file_content = ""
        
        #Replace text
        for line in xml_file:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            new_line = stripped_line.replace("Green plant", "Plant")
            new_file_content += new_line + "\n"
        xml_file.close()
        
        #Overwrites old file content with new file content
        write_file = open(file)
        write_file.write(new_file_content)
        write_file.close()
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following:

```
  File "xml_text_replacer.py", line 13, in <module>
    xml_file = open(file)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Name_of_very_first_xml_file_in_directory.xml'
```

I tried to write an `if` statement to open each XML file, as you can see in the code. However, it's not iterating like I need it to. As can be seen, there is no iteration, and only the first .xml file in the entire directory is listed. How can this code be corrected to accomplish this task?

Comment: Don't complicate things unnecessarily with tqdm until you've got the basics right. tqdm is obviously just returning the file names - not the absolute path which is what you'll need unless you change your working directory. Better to use glob which will allow you to select only files that match *.xml. Use a proper xml handling module to manipulate your data. Treating it as a plain string is fraught with danger. When you re-open the file for (over)writing, you'll need to pass the 'w' parameter

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT to do the job.

It is following a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[.='Green plant']">
        <xsl:copy>Plant</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the below? (just replace the string).
`zz.xml` contains the xml text from the post.

```
with open('zz.xml') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.replace('<name>Green plant</name>', '<name>Plant</name>')
with open('zz_new.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```